# neo4j - can we create the multiple relationship between same nodes with same relationship type but with different values?

Tags: neo4j

we are trying to achieve something similar- but i just taking a general example below:

1. (A) - [r:ACT_IN {role:'main actor'}]->(m:movie)
2. (A) - [r:ACT_IN {role:'side actor'}]->(m:movie)

Is it possible to create such scenarios? because when i tries to add the second row it doesn't add anything.

Thanks,
Pk!

Comment: Please show the Cypher query are you using to create these nodes and relationships.

Comment: 1. MATCH (a:Actor {name: 'Keanu Reeves'}), (m:Movie {title: 'The Matrix'}) CREATE (a)-[r:ACT_IN {role:'main actor'}]->(m); 

And below will be the future insert query- 

2. MATCH (a:Actor {name: 'Keanu Reeves'}), (m:Movie {title: 'The Matrix'}) CREATE (a)-[r:ACT_IN {role:'side actor'}]->(m);

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly possible. You did not provide your exact Cypher queries, so it is not clear where you went wrong.

However, here is a working example (assuming that the DB already contains those `Actor` and `Movie` nodes):

```
MATCH (a:Actor {name: 'Keanu Reeves'}), (m:Movie {title: 'The Matrix'})
CREATE
  (a)-[r1:ACT_IN {role:'main actor'}]->(m),
  (a)-[r2:ACT_IN {role:'side actor'}]->(m);
```

Comment: Hey Sam, Thanks for the quick reply. 

Let's assume we don't have the second data and we have to keep the first one as well with the second data; maintaining relationships intact. then how we can build the cypher for that.. 

1. MATCH (a:Actor {name: 'Keanu Reeves'}), (m:Movie {title: 'The Matrix'})
CREATE
  (a)-[r1:ACT_IN {role:'main actor'}]->(m);

assuming below will be a future insert query-
2. MATCH (a:Actor {name: 'Keanu Reeves'}), (m:Movie {title: 'The Matrix'})
CREATE
  (a)-[r2:ACT_IN {role:'side actor'}]->(m);

Comment: Yes! its working i was using wrong data before. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Note that in addition to the above, it is possible to have multiple identical relationships too - the data can be the same.